# how to receive GET parameter from current page with js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need to receive get parameter from the current page to do xhr request further. I've tried to set data- tags but I think this kludge is not a good deсition.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try

```js
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

Comment: wow ty it works extremely good

Comment: @arsrevoir you can accept my answer and upvote it 